# Compare elements within two data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two data frames using an if statement, with the output being a new data frame. I'd like to compare data frame A to B and for each element in A that is larger than the corresponding element in B, return 1 else 0.

```
A = 5  3  2
    4  7  1
    1  9  5

B = 1  2  9
    2  5  6
    7  2  3
```

Return:

```
C = 1  1  0
    1  1  0
    0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
#create mask
print (A > B)

       0     1      2
0   True  True  False
1   True  True  False
2  False  True   True

print (A > B).astype(int)

   0  1  2
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
```

Next solution is use [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html), but it is same:

```
print (A.gt(B)).astype(int)

   0  1  2
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1

In [13]: %timeit (A > B).astype(int)
The slowest run took 4.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 908 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit (A.gt(B)).astype(int)
The slowest run took 5.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 901 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare directly which will generate a boolean mask and then cast the `dtype` to int using `astype`:

```
In [36]:
(A > B).astype(int)

Out[36]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
```

The boolean mask looks like:

```
In [37]:
A > B

Out[37]:
       0     1      2
0   True  True  False
1   True  True  False
2  False  True   True
```

Comment: That was easy enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just multiply Boolean True/False by one to get ones and zeros.

```
>>> (A > B) * 1
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
```